# Cancel GitHub invitations to a repository

Tags: github, github-api

There is a way to cancel invitations to a repository, through GitHub API?

I found the following endpoint, but it removes a member from a repository, does not cancel an invitation to a repository.

```
DELETE /teams/<team-id>/memberships/<github-username>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you should be able to do that with this endpoint:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/invitations/#delete-a-repository-invitation

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks but I did not formulated my question clearly. I want to remove the person from a team, not a repo. Question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46933435/cancel-github-invitations-to-a-team